# Pre-rendering tiles fail, only once in a while

Tags: openstreetmap, tiles, mapnik, rendering

I've customized the https://github.com/Overv/openstreetmap-tile-server and broken it down into two images, a Tile-Server and a Postgis-Server. Both Tile Server and PostGIS Server are up and running in my kubernetes cluster.

Tile-Server is deployed with following config:

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Release.Name }}
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ .Release.Name }}
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: {{ .Release.Name }}
        image: {{ .Values.Pod.Image }}:{{ .Values.Pod.ImageTag }}
        args: ["run"]
        ports:
          - containerPort: 80
            name: "osm"
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/mod_tile
          name: osm-storage
        - mountPath: /dev/shm
          name: dshm
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 4
            memory: 64Gi
          limits:
            cpu: 4
            memory: 64Gi
        
        env:
          - name: ALLOW_CORS
            value: enabled
          - name: PGHOST
            value: "{{ .Values.Pod.ServiceNamePostgis}}"
          - name: PGUSER
            value: password
          - name: PGPASS
            value: password

      volumes:
        - name: osm-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: {{ .Release.Name }}-pvc
        - name: dshm
          emptyDir:
            medium: Memory
```

Now I have two questions:

1. When I do `df -h` in Tile-Server pod, I can see that 99GB is allocated to /dev/shm (see screenshot below). But still when rendering tiles, once in a while I get this error `renderd[112]:    reason: Postgis Plugin: ERROR:  could not resize shared memory segment "/PostgreSQL.446172090" to 50438144 bytes: No space left on device`. Someone please help me understand where the problem is because I can see plenty of free disk space and ram on the Tile-Server
2. Even after rendering zoom levels 0-6, `/var/lib/mod_tile used only 61MB` disk space. Shouldn't this be in GBs? I'm using this command to render tiles - `render_list -n 1 -s /var/run/renderd/renderd.sock -z 0 -Z 6 -m ajt -a -f`

[image]

Comment: Maybe someone at https://help.openstreetmap.org/ can help.